# Crashlytics shows 75% Crash-free users in the Firebase console, but does not shows crash logs?

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

After the recent upload my crash free users percentage got down from 98 to 75 in Firebase console but I can't see any crash logs in console.I don't know what the problem is?

Comment: Just to be sure, are you talking about OOM crashes?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. My solution is to upload my dSym files to Fabric/Crashlytics, when publishing a new version of my app. Maybe you have the same problem.

Just follow this instructions: https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html

Comment: Also pay attention to bitcode settings. By default it's enabled. With bitcode you have to download your dSyms from Apple Servers. Check the fabric docs: https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html#downloading-bitcode-dsyms

Comment: I am facing same problem in Android, can you help me identifying the problem?